# Notepad++ Regex: Find all 1 and 2 letter words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I’m working with a text file with 200.000+ lines in Notepad++. Each line has only one word. I need to strip out and remove all words which only contains one letter (e.g.: *I*) and words which contains only two letters (e.g.: *as*).

I thought I could just pas in regular regex like this `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` but I does not recognize anything (I’m trying to Mark them).

I’ve done manual search and I know that there do exists words of that length so therefor can it only be my regex code that’s wrong. Anyone knows how to do this in Notepad++ ???

Cheers,
- Mestika

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove only the words but leave the lines empty, this works:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
```

Replace this with an empty string. `^` and `$` are anchors for the beginning and the end of a line (because Notepad++'s regexes work in multi-line mode).

If you want to remove the lines completely, search for this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\r\n
```

And replace with an empty string. However, this won't work before Notepad++ 6, so make sure yours is up-to-date.

Note that you will have to replace `\r\n` with the specific line-endings of your file!

As Tim Pietzker suggested, a platform independent solution that also removes empty lines would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[\r\n]+
```

A platform-independent solution that does not remove empty lines but only those with one or two letters would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}(\r\n?|\n)
```

Comment: +1 for the `\r\n` to remove the lines; without it, there would be a lot of blank lines =P

Comment: Or use `[\r\n]+` instead of `\r\n`, then you're platform-independent. That would also remove empty lines at the same time, though, if there are any.

Comment: edited that in, and also a possibility to be platform-independent without removing too many line breaks

Comment: Wasn't the question about removing _words_, not lines? Wasn't it about non-working regex (rather than 'over-working')?

Comment: the first regex only removes the words without removing the lines. also the anchors are quite important, otherwise almost everything will be removed. your answer makes a good point, too, though ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, it has removed the lines successful but my problem was also, which @newfurniturey wrote, that I was using a wrong version of Notepad++ which hadn't got the PCRE engine.. So thank you to both of you

Comment: Cleared. ) Anyway, I somehow missed the point in the question that each word is placed on its own line, so my answer (its part regarding matching the words with `\W+`) was a bit off the mark, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Notepad++ but my guess is it could be because you have too many matches - try including word boundaries (your exp will match every set of 2 letters)

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b
```

Comment: Nice... works  in javascript str.replace(/\b[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}\b/g, "")

Answer (score 1):

The regex you specified should find 1-or-2 characters (even in Notepad++'s Find-dialog), but not in the way you'd think. You want to have the regex make sure it starts at the beginning of the line and ends at the end with `^` and `$`, respecitevely:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
```

[Notepad++ version 6.0](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html) introduced the PCRE engine, so if this doesn't work in your current version try updating to the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use the version of Notepad++ that doesn't support explicit quantifiers: that's why there's no match at all (as `{` and `}` are treated as literals, not special symbols).

The solution is to use their somewhat more lengthy replacement:

```
\w\w?
```

... but that's only part of the story, as this regex will match *any* symbol, and not just short words. To do that, you need something like this:

```
^\w\w?$
```